# Declaring babel plugins for @babel/eslint-parser in .eslintrc

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs, eslint

I've been trying for a while now to get `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin to work nicely with `@babel/eslint-parser` and `eslint` without success.

This is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
...
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "requireConfigFile": false,
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel",
  ],
...
```

And these are the related installed packages:

```
+-- @babel/core@7.11.1
+-- @babel/eslint-parser@7.11.3
+-- @babel/eslint-plugin@7.11.3
+-- @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.10.4
+-- eslint@7.7.0
```

---

Under this configuration, ESLint errors with this message:

```
Parsing error: \eg\example.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classPrivateProperties' isn't currently enabled (xx:yy): (Fatal)
```

But if I add `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to `plugins` in `.eslintrc.js` like this:

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  ],
```

I get this error:

```
Error while running ESLint: Failed to load plugin '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '@babel/eslint-plugin-plugin-proposal-class-properties'.
```

---

It seems like this isn't the correct way to declare plugins for `@babel/eslint-parser` in `.eslintrc.js`. Still, I suspect it is possible due to this quote [here](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/07/13/the-state-of-babel-eslint#the-future):

> `@babel/eslint-parser` also supports applying Babel configuration through your ESLint configuration.

### So my question is:

Is it actually possible to declare babel plugins in `.eslintrc`? If so how exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually simpler than I thought...

So it turns out that since `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` is a babel plugin, it needs to be declared in the `plugins` property of babel's configuration. According to [the documentation of `@babel/eslint-parser`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#additional-parser-configuration), those can be passed in with `babelOptions` property.

Therefore it's really as simple as this:

```
...
  "parserOptions": {
    ...
    "babelOptions": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        ...
      ],
    },
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel",
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `@babel/eslint-parser` as eslintrc `parser`, I met this question too.

For example, the `eslintrc` used by eslint node api in a global cli , and the cli provide a command `A`.

After go to the directory `B`, executing command `A`.The `process.cwd()` is `B` directory, but the `@babel/xxx` deps is in cli node_modules.The `babel/core` can not find  plugins in `B`.

```
Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators'\nRequire stack:
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser/lib/worker/babel-core.cjs
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser/lib/worker/handle-message.cjs
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser/lib/client.cjs
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser/lib/index.cjs
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/node_modules/test-a-es-checker/dist/index.js
- /Users/a1/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/test-a-cli/dist/index.js
```

I resolved it by provide `cwd` for babelOption in eslintrc.

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  babelOptions: {
    cwd: __dirname, // The working directory that all paths in the programmatic options will be resolved relative to.
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    ],
  },
  ...
};
```